# why wasn't Yehoshua bin Nun Moshiach?

Tags: torah-reading, messiah, navi-prophets, yehoshua-joshua

He brought the people into the land of Yisroel, conquered their enemies, what more could you ask for?

I heard that if Moshe had been permitted to go into the land, he would've been Moshiach, but why not Yehoshua???

Comment: [Master list](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2044/18112) of "Why isn't <blah> Moshiach?" questions on Meta.

Comment: Such a great man and such a great name, I can see why someome would wonder

Answer (score 3):

the answer is simple (according to [Rambam's rulings on Moshiach here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188356/jewish/Melachim-uMilchamot-Chapter-11.htm))

Moshiach is one who fulfills the following in this order:

1. Brings all Jews to the promised land (check)
2. Fights and wins Amolek (nope)
3. Builds the Temple (nope)
4. Doesn't die *before* completing the list (fail).

So 1 out of 4 - he's not the Moshiach. Please read the link, it's not so long.

---

**Could Moses be the Moshiach:**

It is widely accepted that if Moses would enter the Land of Israel he would eventually COMPLETE THE WHOLE LIST and be the Moshiach, not just because of entering the Land alone as you suggested. Therefore Yehoshua cannot be considered a Moshiach by entering the Promised Land alone.

Comment: It is not that he does not die, but that he does not die before accomplishing the tasks he is required to do. The Rambam says that he will re-establish the Davidic dynasty, not that he will rule as an immortal king

Comment: My question wasn't why wasn't he considered Moshiach in the past, my question was that, just as Moshe was FIT to be Moshiach if he WOULD have gone into the land, why didn't Hashem arrange Hasgacha-pratis in a way that would make Yehoshua MOshiach??? Obviously he WASN'T,, that's not my question, my question is: Why didn't Hashem MAKE him Moshiach?I know we can't ask questions of Hashem, but it's just based on the same idea that IF Moshe wouldn't entered the land he WOULD have been Moshiach if not for the sins, so what sins caused Moshiach NOT to have come then?

Comment: @user2016831 I understand your assumption and added a line in the answer. Please revise.

Comment: @AlBerko " he would eventually COMPLETE THE WHOLE LIST and be the Moshiach, not just because of entering the Land alone as you suggested." It's not merely my suggestion, I'm taking it in a note from here http://chabadlibrary.org/books/admur/mlukat/4/12/index.htm look at note 18 ראה אוה"ת ואתחנן (ע' סה; שם ע' צג, ממג"ע אופן קפו ואוה"ח ר"פ ואתחנן), שאילו הי' משה רבינו מכניס את בני ישראל לארץ ובונה ביהמ"ק, לא הי' נחרב ביהמ"ק לעולם והי' לו קיום נצחי כמו שיהי' לע"ל. ומבאר שם (ע' פז. וראה גם שם כרך ו ע' ב'רכד) דהטעם על זה שלא פעל משה מבוקשו הוא לפי "שמהירידות שנמשכו בגלות הארץ יהי' עלי' גדולה יותר".

Comment: @sabbahillel Since you picked up on it, I’ll continue the thought. If you or AlBerko look in a decent Hebrew dictionary, what does a הרג mean? That’s the actual word Rambam uses for number 4. Also, regarding item 2, didn’t Yehoshuah go out to the war with Amalek in the Chumash? Weren’t they (Israel) victorious?

Comment: @AlBerko The first redeemer is also supposed to be the final redeemer. The soul of Moshe Rabbeinu is dressed in the body of Moshiach. It is the kabbalistic concept of Ibbur.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Yesoshua fought Amalek as the army general under Moshe and not as the melech. Also he won that battle but did not totally destroy Amalek. As for number four, I will have to reread the Rambam

Comment: @sabbahillel True, but he was also the individual who replaced Moshe as leader/King and filled his placed. Regarding point 4, if you re-read Rambam, look up the word root in a good dictionary.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Yes harag means was killed. However, the entire sentence was *that if he did not complete these actions (before he died naturally) or was killed* (before he completed the actions) then he was not the mashiach. Additionally, since he was not a member of the tribe of Yehudah, then he could not be the Mashiach. The Mashiach must be from the proper lineage from the tribe of Yehudah.

Comment: @sabbahillel Thanks for actually checking the wood root meaning & confirming it. Many here have argued with me about that. Concerning your adding to Rambam the phrase in brackets, please keep in mind that Rambam did not use those words. If you are comfortable adding that in order to understand his pasak, that’s fine. But your addition isn’t actually there. Rambam emphasizes in his intro to Mishneh Torah that he was exceedingly precise in exactly what he wrote. Regarding Yehoshua being Moshiach, I don’t understand it that way for a variety of reasons. The issue of lineage is only one of them.

Comment: @sabbahillel What Rambam’s pasak means without your addition is something I will leave for you to ponder. You strike me as someone who tries honestly to understand what the Torah teaches wherever that leads. If we were in the same community & you were open to it, we could sit across the table from each other and learn it together.

Comment: @sabbahillel Trying to be true to Rambam’s usage, it actually has a connotation of murder through ambush. See Bereshit 37:20 and 37:26, 2 Shmuel 3:30. It is not about death by any natural means. And if you are feeling ambitious, you should investigate the difference between the usage of הרג in contrast and comparison to רצח, which means murder, and מות which means die in Tanach. Then you will have a better understanding of what Rambam is truly saying there.